# Get WiFi router info delivered through LAN port

Tags: networking

I have 2 routers in my house. Router 1 is downstairs, provided by the ISP, most devices are connected to this.

Upstairs, I have router 2. This one serves my bedroom which has the file server.

In order to access the files from the server through Router 1, I can plug the ethernet cable which has the internet into one of the LAN ports on Router 2. This then turns it into a switch and all is well.

However, the WiFi connection on Router 2 no longer works. Is there anyway to get the WiFi internet connection through one of the LAN ports? Router 2 is rather old (Netgear WGR614). If this isn't possible, what router would I need to buy to enable me to do this.

Would I need a 'network bridge'? Honestly, I have no idea, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean that router 2 stops advertising the Wi-Fi network entirely, or that the network is still there but connecting to it no longer provides an IP address, or that an address is provided but you have no Internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to bridge the Netgear's LAN switch and the Wi-Fi access point... but practically all home routers already do that by default, indeed in many that's the only option in the first place. So in other words, it should already work.

However, when you're connecting the cable from router 1 to router 2's LAN port, *make sure* that you don't end up with both routers as DHCP servers. All your devices are supposed to use router 1 as the gateway, so they need to to get DHCP leases from router 1 as well. In your case it sounds like Wi-Fi clients pick up offers from router 2 first (the earliest offer wins) and use it as the gateway – which of course won't work with no WAN connection.

Comment: Hi, when turning DHCP off on Router 2, anything connected to Router 2 doesn't get an assigned IP address. Even when you manually enter an IP address to a WiFi device, the connection doesn't work. I cannot find any bridging capabilities in the settings of Router 2.